# LDAP and MS Exchange Integration

Tags: ldap, exchange

We have an existing LDAP server and We wish use its accounts in a new MS Exchange. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible. All versions of Exchange after 2000 have required Active Directory for all accounts. Even if you run Samba as an AD server (recent builds can do this, mostly) it doesn't work since Exchange requires bits that the Samba project hasn't gotten around to yet, or is still being developed.

Answer (score 1):

Is your LDAP server a windows AD domain controller? If it is not, you won't be able to utilize it.  Exchange heavily relies on Active Directory.